# Confused about Op Amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, kirchhoffs-laws

So in the linear operating range of an op amp the output is A(Vp-Vn) where Vp is the voltage at the positive terminal and Vn is the voltage at the negative terminal.  But that does not seem to always be the case when I am doing my homework problems.  It seems that the output voltage is whatever is needed to keep the rest of the circuit valid according to Kirchhoff's Laws.  Is that a correct assessment or am I missing something?

Comment: Your open loop gain, A, if not constrained by negative feedback will be huge (think 500k - 1m). If you put even a small difference of voltage between the inverting and non-inverting terminals, that small voltage will be amplified and slam against your positive or negative rails. If you have an input signal on your non-inverting terminal, and a wire connecting your output to your inverting terminal, then yes, the Opamp will adjust the output to make the voltage difference between the inverting and non-inverting input zero.

Comment: An open loop op amp is a comparator. With 3 states. If you want to use it in calculations then you will have +vcc in output for Vin+ > Vin-, zero volt for Vin + = Vin- and- vcc for Vin +< Vin-

Comment: In reality though an open loop op amp comparator only really has two states, your +Vcc (Vin+ > Vin-) and -Vcc (Vin+ < Vin-) states. Even if you wired your inverting and non-inverting terminals together, the tiny internal input offset voltage that exists in real op-amps would get amplified by your massive A and slam your output against one of the rails.

Comment: In an ideal op-amp, A is infinity. Solve your circuit assuming the output = A(Vp-Vn) but Vp ≠ Vn, and then take the limit as A equals infinity. You will find that this result is the same as the result you're getting doing your homework—this is because the "Vp = Vn" assumption in your homework is a result of A→∞ in negative feedback. (As MichaelK mentions, A in reality is big but not infinite - the bigger it is, the closer Vn and Vp will be and the closer the real opamp circuit will be to an ideal opamp.)

Comment: The keyword is "negative feedback". You should try to become familiar with the feedback principle - and its benefits and consequences.

Comment: Your question is very similar to this one: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/142375/assumptions-for-an-op-amp-and-when-they-do-and-dont-hold?rq=1
Basically, ideal op-amps have infinite gain and will do "whatever it takes" to keep the assumptions true. But real op-amps do not have infinite gain, and have other limitations, also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both statements are correct, but you are apparently confusing things. The first statement is *what values may the output actually achieve* and that is indeed limited by the power rails.

What the output will achieve in a particular circuit will (provided there is negative feedback) be somewhere between the power rails such that the difference between the inputs is zero, *provided* it is possible for the output to achieve it.

Consider the circuit below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flYOqQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This amplifier has a non-inverting gain of 2. If we set Vin to be 2V, then the output can go to 4V, keeping the inverting input at the same 2V, *but* if we were to set Vin to be 3V, an output of 6V cannot be achieved; the maximum is 5V (in a practical device this may not be achievable, but I will leave that alone for now).

With 5V at the output, the inverting input cannot be higher than 2.5V, leaving a differential voltage between the inputs.